# Low quality Images on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am absolutely clueless regarding an issue i am having with blurry images on iOS.

I am working with react, and i am using @use-gesture library ([use-gesture.netlify.app](https://use-gesture.netlify.app)) to enable pinch zoom on some small images and videos. It all works like a charm on desktop, but on my mobile device images are always blurry-bad-quality when pinch-zoomed. Videos are not affected by that quality loss. I don´t think it has anything todo with @use-gesture, since ive been using a lightbox component before that and had the same issue.

I've already read every single thread i could find regarding image scale on iOS but wasnt able to find a solution yet.

What i've gathered/tried so far:

Adding to index.html:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,minimum-scale=1">
```

and adding this to the img tag:

```
 resizeMode="contain"
 aspectRatio="1.5"
 height= "undefined"
 width= "undefined"
```

Does it maybe have something to do with a difference in image rendering on mobile devices, to me it seems like images dimensions are defined onLoad in the size of my thumbnails and original image size/resolution is ignored? idk..

This is the code of a complete re-build of the issue i am having based on a new react project but i  still get the same effect

```
import test from './imgtest.jpg';
import './App.css';
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useSpring, animated } from "react-spring";
import { createUseGesture, dragAction, pinchAction } from '@use-gesture/react'

const useGesture = createUseGesture([dragAction, pinchAction])

function App() {

  useEffect(() => {
    const handler = e => e.preventDefault()
    document.addEventListener('gesturestart', handler)
    document.addEventListener('gesturechange', handler)
    document.addEventListener('gestureend', handler)
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('gesturestart', handler)
      document.removeEventListener('gesturechange', handler)
      document.removeEventListener('gestureend', handler)
    }
  }, [])
  const ref = React.useRef(null)

  const [style, api] = useSpring(() => ({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    scale: 1,
    rotateZ: 0,
    config: {

  },
  }))

  useGesture(
    {
      onPinch: ({ origin: [ox, oy], first, active, movement: [ms], offset: [s, a], memo }) => {
        if (first) {
          const { width, height, x, y } = ref.current.getBoundingClientRect()
          const tx = ox - (x + width / 2)
          const ty = oy - (y + height / 2)
          memo = [style.x.get(), style.y.get(), tx, ty]
        }

        const x = memo[0] - (ms - 1) * memo[2]
        const y = memo[1] - (ms - 1) * memo[3]
        api.start({ scale:  s , offset: active ? x : 0, offset: active ? y : 0 })
        return memo
      },
    },
    {
      target: ref,
      pinch: { scaleBounds: { min: 1, max: 4 }, rubberband: true },
    }
  )

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <animated.div  ref={ref} style={style}>
        <img 
        resizeMode="contain"
        aspectRatio="1.5"
        height= "undefined"
        width= "undefined" 
        src={test} 
        className="App-logo"
        />
      </animated.div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Please can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

IOS devices have different DPIs than desktops. You need a bigger image to get a clear image.

also check out this [link](https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/WinUI3/html/DPI.htm)

Comment: Images resolution should be way enough, i am working with 2500x3000 px at 144ppi